# Magento stock and inventory extension?

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I'm looking for a good stock and inventory management extension for Magento 1.5.1 that extends the basic reports , I've had a look around and can't seem to find the right one , does anybody have any ideas ?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you describe what is missing in standard magento ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ PeopleVox's web based inventory management system that integrates with Magento: http://www.peoplevox.co.uk/magento